# PDFLateX doesn't work the second time

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texmaker

I just installed MiKTeX and Texmaker. I am Using Windows 7, Texmaker 4.2 and MiKTeX 2.9. However, I have he following problem:

If there is just the .tex file and the files for included pictures in the corresponding folder, then PDFLaTeX works fine and by pressing "View PDF" I can also see the document in the PDF Viewer in Texmaker.

During this first compilation, there are some new files created including a .synctex.gz file.

Now the following happens: 
1.) If I delete the .synctex.gz file, then I can recompile the with PDFLaXeX and display it with "View PDF" as usual.
2.) If I do not delete the .synctex.gz file, then recompiling with PDFLaTeX and pressing "View PDF" results in the error "File not found". Furthermore there is an additional file .synctex.gz(busy) created (so there is a .synctex.gz file and a .synctex.gz(busy) file in the folder with the same name). If I delete both of them, it works again as in 1.)

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you cut down your MWE to a simple document and an image from the [`mwe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe) package that shows the problem, it should be much easier to answer. Often second-build errors are due to odd things being written into the .toc, .aux, or similar files.